# How much standing do I lose for declining a mission from an agent?

Tags: eve-online

I'm running faction warfare missions, which are distributed all over the enemy low-sec. To optimize the mission running I'm trying to get missions that are close together, but I can only decline missions without standing loss once every four hours.

If I could decline missions more often, it would make it easier to optimize the routes and get misssions that are close together. What I'd like to know is *how much* standing I lose when declining a mission, that would make it easier to gauge how often I can decline missions without hurting my standings long-term.

How much faction, corporation and agent standing do I lose for declining a mission? How much is that in comparison to the standings I gain, so what percentage of missions can I decline and have my standings stable over time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this source](http://eve-search.com/thread/1248642/page/1), "you get a standing loss equal to the standing you would have gained if you accepted and completed the mission" within the critical 4 hours scope... I have no idea how confident you can be with this information, as the source is not an official document (even if part of the official Eve wiki). A good part of the standing math is explained [here](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Standings_mechanics), if you do not already know this page.

Good luck, and I hope I did not help a Caldari state agent today... :)

Answer (score 0):

IF you decline a mission more then once every 4 hours with a particular agent, you will loose standings to that agent, her division, and her faction. While the loss to faction is not severe, you normally only GAIN faction standings through story-line missions (every 16 missions).

It is highly recommended that you do not decline missions that incur standings loss, because some of those standings will not be easily recovered just by accepting the next mission.

P.S. I feel the need to point out I do not know if faction warfare missions behave differently, but regular missions are this way.

P.P.S. Also, this is PER agent, when I have to decline a mission, I move to one of my secondary agents and work with them for a while (usually until I have to decline from them as well).

Happy hunting!